# Как отобразить телетекст в MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отобразить телетекст *(который обычно находится на 888 странице)* в **MediaPlayer** в **AndroidStudio**?

Я пытался это сделать так:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void setSubtitles(Context ctx, int trackIndex) {
        try {
            _mp.addTimedTextSource(ctx, uri, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
            int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(trackIndex, MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT);
            _mp.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("setSubtitles", "error: " + Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
        }

        _mp.setOnTimedTextListener(new MediaPlayer.OnTimedTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimedText(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, final TimedText timedText) {
                if (timedText != null) {
                    Log.d("onTimedText", "subtitle: " + timedText.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Но к сожалению не работает. Не находит ни одной дорожки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать?

Проверяю на трансляции телеканала **"Карусель"**.